# Have to run all python scripts with sudo

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, sudo

I got a new Raspberry Pi, installed Ubuntu on it, wrote a python script but when I run the script using `python3 script.py` it just cant find libraries that I installed using pip3 and give library missing erros.

But if I run the same script using `sudo python script.py` it runs.

I have given script.py permission using `sudo chmod 777 script.py` , yet same issue

I even gave folder permissions `sudo chown user user /home/someuser/Desktop` , yet same problem

Now the bigger problem is when I use basic IDE like Thonny , I cant run using sudo from the IDE itself , so I have to run the script from terminal separately which is such a pain

Here is my file permissions
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 someuser someuser 2528 Dec 19 17:57  script.py`

Here is my folder permissions
`drwxr-xr-x 3 someuser someuser 4096 Dec 19 17:56 Desktop`

**There is no other user on the system except for the one I created during ubuntu setup**

I have mostly installed all libraries using sudo pip3 install

One of the error I am getting while trying to use GPIO library

```
  File "/home/someuser/Desktop/beep.py", line 11, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!
```

Another error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 231, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Is there a way where I dont have to use sudo every time and makes life easy and easily work with installed libraries.

Here is some additional info

```
/usr/lib/python38.zip
/usr/lib/python3.8
/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/home/someuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

```
someuser@pi4:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root

Answer (score 1):

did you use sudo to install libraries, if so you, thats why its not available for your current user.

install packages with `pip install --user <package_name>` to install them for current user.

or

use a `virtualenv`

Comment: Installed new ubuntu , only did sudo apt-get update, not when I run ```pip install --user RPi.GPIO``` it erros out with ```Building wheels for collected packages: RPi.GPIO
  Building wheel for RPi.GPIO (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Comment: there is no way its letting me install RPi.GPIO without sudo. Please help . Same problem again

Comment: Had to install library using ```sudo apt-get install rpi.gpio```